# detect of iOS 8 quicktype keyboard is opened or closed without notification

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

I have us that attempts to display itself above the keyboard and should not move once the keyboard is opened.

I can adjust where it displays but with the quicktype keyboard I can't determine the height of the keyboard unless I know if the quicktype is opened or close. Is there any way I can determine this?

Comment: Take a look at my solution in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213681/ios-8-keyboard-hides-my-textview/26226732#26226732

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the `keyboardWillShow`: notification to adjust other views frames.

A notification is posted to `keyboardWillShow`: not only on `becomeFirstResponder` for a textView/Field but also when the user shows/hides the quick type keyboard.

once the `keyboardWillShow`: notification has been posted, the keyboard's frame can be captured by the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` in the notification object.

An example of a `textView` that adjusts its frame based on the keyboard:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
  NSTimeInterval duration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
  UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    self.textViewVisualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(self.textViewVisualEffectView.origin.x, self.view.height - keyboardRect.size.height - self.textViewVisualEffectView.height, self.textViewVisualEffectView.width, self.textViewVisualEffectView.height);

  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }];
}
```

Comment: at this point in my code the keyboard has never shown and hence no notification.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of the asker said about the quicktype area above the keyboard. Yes, the keyboard size is captured on launch, but the quicktype area isn't included in the launch. So when the user starts inputting text, the quicktype area is displayed. The quicktype area hides some of the screen.